# Totalling the checked checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Now the requirement is i have a checkbox in front of all the records. when i check the it has to add the Total field of that particular row id total and show the totals in another field called Grand_total. For Example if i check the first record id1 and third record id3, it has to show me a Grand_Total of 3700.00 (2500.00 + 1200.00). What is the best way to achieve this? Is it javascript or php? Pls help me?

This is what i have tried.
       
       
        
         $('input').change(function() {
        recalcTotal();
       });

```
function recalcTotal() {
var total12 = 0;
$('input:checked').each(function() {
    total12 += $(this).data('tot'); 
});

$('#total12').html(total12);
}
</script>
<body>
 <input type='checkbox' data-tot='{$list5['margin_for']}' name='gt' id='gt'>   
 <input size='8' type='text' id='margin_for[]' name='margin_for[]' value='{$list5['margin_for']}' readonly>

<div id="total12"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: i have updated what i have tried. Really appreciate if someone can guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that your function is not getting called anywhere.call your function `recalcTotal()` on `checkbox click`. Try this:

```js
function recalcTotal() {
var total12 = 0;
$('input:checked').each(function() {
    total12 += $(this).data('tot'); 
});

$('#total12').val(total12);
}
$("input[type='checkbox']").on("click",function(){
  
  recalcTotal();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
 <input type='checkbox' data-tot='100' name='gt1' id='gt1'>   
 <input size='8' type='text' id='margin_for[]' name='margin_for[]' value='100' readonly>
  
  <input type='checkbox' data-tot='50' name='gt' id='gt'>   
 <input size='8' type='text' id='margin_for[]' name='margin_for[]' value='50' readonly>
  <input name="grandTotal" id="total12" readonly/>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. How will i show the Grand Total value in a field? As of now its showing in a <div>

Comment: Then only i can insert the value to the mysql db...

Comment: @SanjuMenon try the updated one and if it helps you the you can mark it as answer.

Comment: @SanjuMenon for you note:marking the correct answer and upvoting it helps the later user,so in a way of doing this you are help the later visitor of SO,so Please mark and upvote only the best answer not just any random.

Comment: Yesterday itself i have marked it as correct answer.

Comment: @SanjuMenon not that man i'm just giving you advise guessing you may be a new user.

Comment: i understand. Yes iam new to this site.